# Metric Absence Alert on Logs-based Metrics from Pod Triggered on Pod Reschedule

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine, stackdriver, google-cloud-stackdriver, google-cloud-monitoring

## Setup

> *Note: Using pseudo-code instance notation: `ObjectType("<name>", | <attr>: <attr-value>])`.*

We have a Container:
`Container("k8s-snapshots")` in a `Pod("k8s-snapshots-0")` in a `StatefulSet("k8s-snapshots", spec.replicas: 1)

We expect at most 1 Pod to run at any point in time.

We have a Logs-based `Counter` `Metric("k8s-snapshots/snapshot-created")` with the filter:

```
resource.type="container"
resource.labels.cluster_name="my-cluster"
logName="projects/my-project/logs/k8s-snapshots"
jsonPayload.event:"snapshot.created"
```

We have a Stackdriver Policy:

```
Policy(
  Name: "snapshot metric absent",
  Condition: Condition(
    Metric("k8s-snapshots/snapshot-created"),
    is absent for: "more than 30 minutes"
  )
)
```

In order to monitor if `Container("k8s-snapshots")` has stopped creating snapshots.

## Expected result

An alert is triggered if no instance of `Pod("k8s-snapshots-0")` has logged any event matching `Metric("k8s-snapshots/snapshot-created")`.

## Result

`Policy(Name: "snapshot metric absent")` is violated each time `Pod("k8s-snapshots-0")` is rescheduled.

It seems like a sub-metric of the main logs-based metric is created for each instance of `Pod("k8s-snapshots")`, and Stackdriver alerts for each sub-metric.

Answer (score 0):

Are you still experiencing the issue? With[Stackdriver API](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/api/v3/filters#metric-descriptor-filter) you have the ability to aggregate metrics (You can have custom metrics) which the UI does not have until now. You can also visit this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44808047/stackdriver-custom-metric-aggregate-alerts)